# Каким ПО можно мониторить то, какие ip сети стучатся в определенный список адресов интернета?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, ip, мониторинг

Каким ПО можно мониторить то, какие ip сети стучатся в определенный список адресов интернета?

Comment: можно определить снифером

Comment: wireshark вполне себе

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) , как-то очень давно работал с ней, но она показала себя не очень хорошо с большими объёмами трафика, хотя может быть что я просто не понял как её готовить. А вообще, ищите любой ids, они обладают необходимым Вам функционалом.